# "By what percent?" vs. "By how much percentage?"

Tags: grammar

if someone says the price of a certain item has dropped (I made it up), can I ask her/him: "By what percent?" and/or "By how much percentage?" Thank you.

Comment: You can either use "By how much" (absolute number of $ of the decrease in price) or "By what percentage"

Answer (score 0):

One could use either "*By how many percent?*" or "*By what percentage*".

"*By how much percentage?*" might be short for "*By how much, as a percentage*".
It is acceptable in informal use, but is best avoided.